# How can I auto-generate SQL statements without triggering Findbugs's SQL injection warning?

Tags: java, sql, findbugs

For example, in my code there are some places where the number of question marks in my source query changes based on some feature of the data. I am not placing user data in the SQL, but I am adjusting the number of question marks. The only way to do this is with String concatenation/formatting/etc, which trigger this warning from Findbugs:

> A prepared statement is generated from a nonconstant String

Is there a (non-code-smell) way to auto-generate SQL without making Findbugs think it's a vulnerability?

Example code for what I have now:

```
final static String BASE_SQL = "SELECT * FROM customers WHERE id IN (questionMarkPlaceholder)";

[...]

final String questionMarks = "?" + StringUtils.repeat(", ?", customers.length - 1);
final String sql = BASE_SQL.replaceFirst("questionMarkPlaceholder", questionMarks);
statement = conn.prepareStatement(sql);

int counter = 1;
for (Customer customer : customers) {
    statement.setString(counter, customer.getId());
    counter++;
}

resultSet = statement.executeQuery();
```

Comment: This ***is*** a vulnerability, it's not a false positive, it's not being over sensitive.  Don't substitute the string in your self, prepare the query with parameters

Comment: I'm open to that, but I'm unaware of any way to do that if I don't know the number of parameters I need ahead of time. Any suggestions?

Comment: @MatBailie While I would hesitate to call this secure simply because I have never dealt (or watch others deal with) this kind of code, I fail to see any way this could be exploited. Do you have any idea?

Comment: If you don't know how many parameters you will need, how do you know how many question marks you will need?

Comment: I do know how many parameters I need, but only at runtime, not at compile time.

Comment: FindBugs is just a software tool. You shouldn't code to make it happy. You understood its warning, are smarter than it is and thus know that this code is OK. So add a SuppressWarning annotation to remove this warning, and work on something more useful.

Answer (score 1):

There are some persistence apis that doesn't require manual string concatenation for dynamic number of parameters.
[Hibernate Criteria](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/querycriteria.html) and [Querydsl](http://www.querydsl.com/) have DSL that avoid this problem.

In your particular case, the query is not vulnerable since the values are not coming from a user input. The FindBugs warning can be consider false positive. If you identify that the values could be control by a remote user, you can use ESAPI utility class [Encoder.encodeForSQL](http://owasp-esapi-java.googlecode.com/svn/trunk_doc/latest/org/owasp/esapi/Encoder.html).

Answer (score 0):

The best way I've seen to do this is to use a handful of predefined queries (this may or may not work for your situation).  There are two advantages to using the parameter place holders with prepared statements.  One is the protection from SQL injection but also you gain a performance benefit from reusing the compiled query.  The approach defines several sizes of batches:

```
private static final String QUERY_SIZE_SINGLE = "SELECT * FROM customers WHERE id=?";
private static final String QUERY_SIZE_SMALL = "SELECT * FROM customers WHERE id IN (?,?,?)";
private static final String QUERY_SIZE_MEDIUM = "SELECT * FROM customers WHERE id IN (?,?,?,?,?,?)";
private static final String QUERY_SIZE_LARGE = "SELECT * FROM customers WHERE id IN (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)"
private static final int SINGLE = 1;
private static final int SMALL = 3;
private static final int MEDIUM = 6;
private static final int LARGE = 12;

//in your query code...
int remainingCustomers = customers.size();
while (remainingCustomers > 0){
  PreparedStatement ps;
  if (remainingCustomers > LARGE){
     ps = con.prepareStatement(QUERY_SIZE_LARGE);
    //loop through the first LARGE parameters and set them
    remainingCustomers -= LARGE;
   }else if (remainingCustomers > MEDIUM){
   ///so on
   ...
   }//end if
    //execute the statement
    //add results to a temporary list holding the results
}//end while
```

Basically the idea here is that you batch the queries based on the number of customers.  The query sizes I chose are completely arbitrary.  Ideally you would choose these numbers based on what values are common for your application to minimize database round trips.  This approach allows you to take advantage of the benefits of prepared statements while minimizing database round trips (i.e. slow IO operations).

**Note:** I wish I could take credit for this approach but I discovered it while searching for an answer to a similar problem and no longer remember where I found it...